# Print Image in Server side on Button Click by Client

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create such a website, that when a user visits my website and presses a button **it would print an image to my local printer**. I tried to search an solution on the internet but couldnt find anything or any kind of documentation that helps with it.

The duplicate didn't solve my problem. I don't want to print the image to client.

I just want to print the image in **my printer** ( server side)

Comment: With a question like this it's best for you to step back and think of each step required to make this possible... **1.** how to make your compuputer aware of a client event (click) **2.** how to retrieve the data from the client event **3.** print the image from the data retrieved. **Tip:** Dealing with live data you might want to look into using web sockets. This way you could build an admin panel (for your access only), when a client clicks you can send the image data to your computer via the admin panel and have a function print each time data is received.

Comment: Guys, this question didn't show any research effort. But still it worth something.

Comment: @SagarV I agree, the question is very interesting but it isn't very suitable. As you have pointed out- no research attempts, also no existing source code to work with as no specific programming issue exists. The best I can help with this is in the comments section, no correct answer/solution can be given.

Comment: What technologies are you using on the server side? You can allow the users to upload/send an image to your server to print but without knowing what you're using no one can help other than give vague answers

Comment: @AudriusAlekna Remeber me about this question on day after tomorrow and I will offer a bounty.

Comment: I would like to use node.js for backend. I found a similar solution that prints image to a computer, but as I mentioned I need to print it  on my local printer, not on users printer.

Comment: But what are you using to send the print request... you will need something to tell the printer to print. Example another computer... Maybe possible if the server is connected to the printer. If the server is hosted via a company/paid hosting then I doubt you can send a print request otherwise people could use a paid hosting to spam random printers around the world. (Just assuming) I haven't done any background on this and at this moment in time it isn't something I have time to look into so I can be of no further assistance. I wish you luck.

Comment: Maybe this might be of some use? It might be miles from the mark but a quick search and I think this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58Ti8w1yX2w

Comment: I want to build server on my own computer